# "this expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated" error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use an SQL statement for a recordsource of a report using VBA. I know that the SQL works because I copied the SQL from a  SQL view of a query which was working.

Here it the SQL recordsource that fires on open event of a report. I made one change to the SQL statement which was adding a variable `strInput` which you can see in the WHERE clause.

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim sql As String
Dim strInput As String
strInput = Me.OpenArgs

sql = "SELECT DISTINCTROW INV.NUM, INV.SUB, [INVD]![QTY]*([INVD]![VDR]+[INVD]![MATQ]) AS Expr1, [INVD]![QTY]*[INVD]![LPR] AS Expr2, [Expr1]+[Expr2] AS Expr3, [INVD]![MATQ]+[INVD]![VDR] AS Expr4, ([INVD]![MATQ]+[INVD]![VDR])*[INVD]![QTY]*0.8 AS Expr5" & _
    " FROM (JOBS INNER JOIN UN ON JOBS.UNID = UN.JOBS) INNER JOIN ((CONT INNER JOIN INV ON CONT.CTNO = INV.CTNO) INNER JOIN INVD ON (INV.CTNO = INVD.CTNO) AND (INV.INV = INVD.INV)) ON (UN.UNID = INVD.UNID) AND (UN.CTNO = INVD.CTNO)" & _
    " WHERE (((INV.JOB) = [Forms]![02- UNIT JOB INVOICE ENTRY]![JOB])) AND InvNum = ' " & strInput & "'" & _
    " ORDER BY INV.CTNO, INV.JOB, INV.INV, INVD.ITEM;"

If Me.OpenArgs <> "" Then
    Me.RecordSource = sql
    End If



End Sub
```

The error that I get is

> this expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be
>   evaluated

I know that there are similar threads open but those solutions did not work for me. Thank you.

Edit 1 :

Based on your reply I deleted the on open procedure and tried utilizing the where clause like you said

```
MsgBox strInput
DoCmd.OpenReport "PRINT REPORT", acPreview, , "INVD.InvNum =' " & strInput & "'"
```

This is now giving me the same error

> this expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be
>   evaluated

Comment: Instead of setting RecordSource in VBA, just apply the filter criteria of strInput in the OpenReport method. In fact, I would include both parameters in the OpenReport command instead of using WHERE clause. If the report is designed with Sorting & Grouping features, the ORDER BY clause will be ignored. Don't include space after the apostrophe.

Comment: Please check Edit 1

Comment: Remove the space after apostrophe. What is content of strInput?

Comment: Sorry I was just using MsgBox to test value. I am collecting the actual value using input box like this

`strInput = InputBox("Which invoice did you want to print?")`

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment. Validating user input to InputBox is difficult. Recommend input to a control on form.

Comment: The contetnt of strInout should be numbers like 1 , 2 ,3 etc but it's data type is short text. I reverted back to using openargs for openreport method as filter was not working. I also want to let you know that I changed the where clause contidition to this

`" WHERE (((INV.JOB) = [Forms]![02- UNIT JOB INVOICE ENTRY]![JOB]))`

The entire SQL statement beside this remaided the same. This was working as a recordsource and showing me data in the report. I can also confirm that I am obtaining the openargs value because 

`MsgBox strInput` returns 2 which is the value I entered in the form.

Comment: This means with 100 % certanity the error is in this line 


`" WHERE (((INV.JOB) = [Forms]![02- UNIT JOB INVOICE ENTRY]![JOB])) AND InvNum = ' " & strInput & "'" & _`

 specifically after the AND clause

Comment: Thank you for taking your time sir and giving me directions. I will update the solution below. That was a really stupid mistake. I put ' ' around strInput because InvNum has short text datatype in the table properties.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the string quotation from the WHERE clause because InvNum was a number. The final Where clause looks like this

```
WHERE (((INV.JOB)=[Forms]![02- UNIT JOB INVOICE ENTRY]![JOB])) AND INVD.[InvNum] = " & strInput
```